# Different number of TH's compared to columns in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I have just one `th` that fits full width across the table, even if the below table has 5 columns?

I am trying to fill the `th` with a background colour that goes full width. But the rest of the table has 5 columns, so the singular `th` fits to the first column.

```
<tr class="table-title">
    <th>LED</th>
</tr>
<tr class="top">
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Product Description</td>
    <td>Panel Size</td>
    <td>Weekly Price Per Panel</td>
    <td>Weekly Price Per Square Metre</td>
</tr>
```

### JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vnvn0qbz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use colspan attribute of html:

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

```html
<table border="1px">
<tr class="table-title">
    <th colspan="5">LED</th>
</tr>
<tr class="top">
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Product Description</td>
    <td>Panel Size</td>
    <td>Weekly Price Per Panel</td>
    <td>Weekly Price Per Square Metre</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `colspan`, like so:

```
<tr class="table-title">
    <th colspan="5">LED (this should be full width of the table)</th>
</tr>
```

This allows you to define how many columns the element should span, you just need to make it match your columns count, in this instance: `5`

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/6xdz04j6/)

---

For future reference, there is also a `rowspan` attribute which allows you to do the same but for rows instead of columns. You can even mix the 2 up and create some funky looking layouts.

Answer (score 3):

Just add colspan="number of columns" to th like that :

```
<table class="led">
    <tr class="table-title">
        <th colspan="5">LED (this should be full width of the table)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="top">
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Product Description</td>
        <td>Panel Size</td>
        <td>Weekly Price Per Panel</td>
        <td>Weekly Price Per Square Metre</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```